# Basic scatter plot with reference data on diagonal (identity line)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter

I have two arrays x,y obtained from a machine learning calculations and I wish to make a scatter plot with the reference data x on the diagonal in a way to visualize better the predicted values y against the true ones x. Please can you suggest me how to do it in python or gnuplot?

Comment: A better description of what you are trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: I wish to have the x data along the y=x line in the (x,y) so I can see how the y data predicted by Kernel Ridge regression distributed around it. I hope this reply makes the question more clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)

colors = np.random.rand(N)

plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors)
plt.plot( [0,1],[0,1] )
plt.savefig('a.png')
```

This will produce:

[image]

Check [this page](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

a simple example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.linspace(0,100,101) 
y=np.random.normal(x)    # add some noise

plt.plot(x,y,'r.') # x vs y
plt.plot(x,x,'k-') # identity line

plt.xlim(0,100)
plt.ylim(0,100)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In matplotlib, you can also draw an "infinite" line in order to avoid having to define the exact coordinates. For example, if you have an axes `ax`, you can do:

```
pt = (0, 0)
ax.axline(pt, slope=1, color='black')
```

where `pt` is an intersection point. Note if `pt` isn't included in the limits of the plot, the limits will be modified to include it.